# SQL Comparing two aggrigate functions in the having cluse

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, correlated-subquery, having-clause

See the following query from:
http://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/understanding-correlated-subquery/

```
SELECT t1.categoryID, categoryName
From products t1 INNER JOIN  categories c ON c.categoryID = t1.categoryID
GROUP BY categoryID
HAVING MAX(unitprice) > ALL(
                             SELECT  2 * AVG(unitprice)
                             From products t2
                             WHERE t1.categoryID = t2.categoryID)
```

Can we use HAVING MAX(unitprice) > 2 * AVG(unitprice)  instead? The question is can we compare
Two aggregate functions in the same having clause? I see they always nest the second aggregate, why?

Comment: ... I think I dislike their example.  For one thing, that's not going to work anywhere except MySQL (probably), due to `categoryName` not being included in an aggregate or the `GROUP BY` (which in general is dangerous, although should be safe here).  In the real world (as this isn't correlated), I'd probably have gone with `SELECT C.categoryId, C.categoryName FROM Categories C JOIN (SELECT categoryId FROM Products GROUP BY categoryId HAVING MAX(unitPrice) > 2 * AVG(unitPrice)) P ON P.categoryId = C.categoryId`.  Using a correlation just to say you are is likely to bring performance problems.

Comment: Also, the statement will probably throw a syntax error in _any_ RDBMS, because `GROUP BY categoryId` is referring to an ambiguous instance.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can have `HAVING MAX(unitprice) > 2 * AVG(unitprice)`. You retrieve the MAX out of the group of `categoryId`. Fact that you have a subquery that uses exactly the same `categoryId` that you use in grouping you can use `AVG(unitprice)` without any doubts.

```
SELECT t1.categoryID, categoryName
From products t1 INNER JOIN  categories c ON c.categoryID = t1.categoryID
GROUP BY categoryID
HAVING MAX(unitprice) > 2 * AVG(unitprice)
```

If your `WHERE` clause in the subquery would contain any other criteria beside the `categoryId` you cannot do this approach.